# Looping and reassigning values

Tags: java, loops

Ok I am having trouble trying to figure out how to make my program loop back to a previous section if the user enters a certain key.  For example if they hit w at any time the program needs to take the to the weight section so they can enter a new weight and the same for h for height.  If you guys could give me some suggestions I would appreciate it.
  Thank you guys : )

```
package Assignments;
```

import java.util.*;
public class assignment3 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Scanner
    Scanner stdIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Variables
    final double METERS_TO_CM = 100;   // The constant to convert meters to centimeters
    final double BSA_CONSTANT = 3600;  // The constant to divide by for bsa
    double bmi;                        // Body Mass Index
    double weight;                     // Weight in kilograms
    double height;                     // Height in meters
    String classification;             // Classifies the user into BMI categories 
    double bsa;                        // Body surface area



    System.out.print("Welcome to the BMI and BSA Calculator to begin enter weight in kilograms.");
    weight = stdIn.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter height in meters: ");
    height = stdIn.nextDouble();
    bmi = weight/(height*height);
    bsa = Math.sqrt(((height*METERS_TO_CM)*weight)/BSA_CONSTANT);


        if (bmi < 18.5)
        {
            classification = "Underweight";
        }
        else if (bmi < 25)
        {
            classification = "Normal";
        }
        else if (bmi < 30)
        {
            classification = "Overweight";
        }
        else
        {
            classification = "Obese";}


            System.out.println("Choose Options below to set height and weight");
            System.out.println("Your classification is: " + classification);
            System.out.println("(H)eight: " + height + " meters");
            System.out.println("(W)eight: " + weight + " kilograms");
            System.out.printf("BMI: %.1f\n", bmi);
            System.out.printf("BSA: %.2f\n", bsa);
            System.out.println("(Q)uit");

            String response = stdIn.next();

            switch (response.charAt(0)) {
            case 'w': response = "Enter new weight: ";
            weight = stdIn.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Choose Options below to set height and weight");
            System.out.println("Your classification is: " + classification);
            System.out.println("(H)eight: " + height + " meters");
            System.out.println("(W)eight: " + weight + " kilograms");
            System.out.printf("BMI: %.1f\n", bmi);
            System.out.printf("BSA: %.2f\n", bsa);
            System.out.println("(Q)uit"); break;

            case 'h': response = "Enter new height";
            height = stdIn.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Choose Options below to set height and weight");
            System.out.println("Your classification is: " + classification);
            System.out.println("(H)eight: " + height + " meters");
            System.out.println("(W)eight: " + weight + " kilograms");
            System.out.printf("BMI: %.1f\n", bmi);
            System.out.printf("BSA: %.2f\n", bsa);
            System.out.println("(Q)uit"); break;

            case 'q': System.exit(0);

            default: 
                System.out.println (response + "Is not a valid option please try again");

            }   


        }









}
```

Comment: `if they hit w at any time the program needs to take the to the weight section` - I think you need to have call back functions to do this. A keyboard event being triggered and checking the key character pressed and calling the corresponding method.

Comment: Would you mind showing me a quick example of a callback.  My professor hasn't taught us this yet and I am having trouble finding an example.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing it all in one giant function, you could separate out the login into smaller functions. Here's the outline

defile function to Get weight input: double getWeight()

defile function to Get height input: double getHeight()

define function to do the math.

define function to show result.

```
main()
  getWeight()
  getHeight()
  doMath()
  showResult()

  Loop
    show options (H/W/Q)
    switch
      case H:
         getHeight()
         doMath()
         showResult()
      case W
         getWeight()
         doMath()
         showResult()
      case Q
         Exit program
     end switch
   end Loop
```

End main()

Comment: Much cleaner. I was thinking that the poster may wish to look at the command pattern as reference http://www.javaworld.com/javatips/jw-javatip68.html

Comment: Ok I put it in a switch statement and it looks like this but when I do enter a h or w it doesn't do anything